# TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined Node Js firebase functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

My code is like this. Here I am using validators to check the validation of addCustomer Details.In validation I am using a reducer function. When I try to post like this in Postman

```
{
   "bio" : "Devon",
   "website" : "user.com",
   "location " : "London, UK"
}
```

It gives an internal server error.

In firebase error groups it looks like this

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
    at exports.reduceUserDetails (/srv/util/validators.js:50:30)
    at exports.addUserDetails (/srv/handlers/customers.js:656:23)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at jsonParser (/srv/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:101:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at FBAuth.admin.auth.verifyIdToken.then.then (/srv/util/fbAuth.js:31:20)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Index.js

```
app.post("/customers",FBAuthCustomer,addCustomerDetails);
app.post("/sellers", FBAuthSeller, addSellerDetails);
app.post("/delivery", FBAuthDelivery, addDeliveryDetails);userdetails.js
```

// Add customer details

```
exports.addCustomerDetails = (req, res) => {
    let userDetails = reduceUserDetails(req.body);

    db.doc(`/customers/${req.user.handle}`)
        .update(userDetails)
        .then(() => {
            return res.json({ message: "Details added successfully" });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
        });
    };
```

validate data

```
    exports.reduceUserDetails = (data) => {
      let userDetails = {};

      if (!isEmpty(data.bio.trim())) userDetails.bio = data.bio;
      if (!isEmpty(data.website.trim())) {
        // https://website.com
        if (data.website.trim().substring(0, 4) !== 'http') {
          userDetails.website = `http://${data.website.trim()}`;
        } else userDetails.website = data.website;
      }
      if (!isEmpty(data.location.trim())) userDetails.location = data.location;

      return userDetails;
      };

      const isEmpty = (string) => {
        if (string.trim() === '') return true;
        else return false;
      };
```

Comment: The error is suggesting that `data.bio` or `data.website` is undefined, but we can't see why that is.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was simple fix. There was nothing wrong in the code. "location " : "London, UK". Here space in the "location" has caused the error.